# C++ Write Run Output to File

Tags: c++, file

I have a program with a small game which I created, I want to save a log at the end of the game which takes all of the 'Run' output to a text file. Its a pretty hefty game which uses multiple different classes and states so I wont be posting the code. However this is my save function:

```
void saveState(){
    string inputFile;
    std::cout << "Please enter a file to write to:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> inputFile;

    std::ofstream myFile;

    myFile.open(inputFile);
    myFile << "Hello";

    myFile.close();

    std::cout << "Saving to file " << inputFile << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any possible way to fetch the output and put it into a text file?

This is my output for reference:
[image]

Also I am using CLion if that means anything?

Comment: ***Is there any possible way to fetch the output and put it into a text file?*** If you have it in some variables in your program then the answer is yes. However we don't have any idea of the structure of your code.

Comment: Is there no simple method to just pull the console outputs and write that to a document? Like I said, my program is pretty big and its for my work so I would rather not share

Comment: On some operating systems you can use an os method to redirect the console to a file and show on the console at the same time. [https://linuxize.com/post/linux-tee-command/](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-tee-command/)

Comment: Here is an example how to do something similar in `c++`: [https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/326447/tee-command](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/326447/tee-command)

Comment: I see, that helps a bit, thank you very much drescherjm!